# Identifying numbers correctly

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have an intent where I might say 'Transfer 4 to Bob' and it identifies this as 'Transfer for to Bob'

Also I might say 'Transfer 10 to Bob and it identifies this as 'Transfer 102 Bob' treating to word to as 2 on the end of the previous number.

What is the best way to get API.AI to recognise these parts correctly so 4 is not for and to is not 2?

Comment: When you say "say", do you mean you are using speech recognition on top of API.AI (in conjunction with the Google Assistant, for example)?

Comment: We are using Google Home which passes this on to API.AI
Another examples of this would be if we were ordering coffee and we said 'Get me 4 lattes' it would come back as get me for lattes
We have tried some of the system entities such as making four a @sys.number and lattes and a custom entity but that didn't work

Also tried sys.unit-information around '4 lattes' in the hope that it would extract 4 as the amount and lattes as the unit but also no luck with that

Comment: What is the recommended way to extract an amount and another value to treat as a unit for things that are not traditional units like weight or length?
Like how would you parse 'Buy 4 umbrellas' or 'Buy 30 apples' which are not traditional units

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you're using the Actions on Google platform. This means that speech recognition - the process of translating what the user says into text - is happening before the data gets to API.AI.

The problem you're experiencing is that Actions on Google is misrecognizing some numbers as words, e.g. `four` becomes `for`.

Because this happens before - and separately from - API.AI, you won't be able to fix the misrecognition.

Below, I'll explain how you can work around this issue in API.AI. However, it's also worth thinking about how you could make your conversation design as robust as possible so that issues like this are less likely to cause problems.

One way you could increase robustness would be to mark the number as a required parameter in API.AI so the user is prompted if it isn't detected due to a recognition error. In that case, the dialog would go like this:

> User: Give me four lattes.
>
> App:  Sure, four lattes coming up.
>
> User: Give me for lattes.
>
> App: How many do you want?
>
> User: Four.
>
> App: Sure, four lattes coming up.

Regardless, here's a workaround you can use to help recover from misrecognition:

1. In your intent, provide examples of these commonly misrecognized values. Highlight and mark them as numbers.

[image: User says statements]

2. Test out your intent out in the console and you'll see that "for" is now matched as a "number" entity with value "for".

[image: Console]

3. In your fulfillment webhook, check the parameter for this value and convert it to the appropriate number using a dictionary. Here's the JSON for the above query:

```
    {
      "id": "994c4e39-be49-4eae-94b0-077700ef87a3",
      "timestamp": "2017-08-03T19:50:26.314Z",
      "lang": "en",
      "result": {
        "source": "agent",
        "resolvedQuery": "Get me for lattes",
        "action": "",
        "actionIncomplete": false,
        "parameters": {
          "drink": "lattes",
          "number": "for" // NOTE: Convert this to "4" in your webhook
        },
        "contexts": [],
        "metadata": {
          "intentId": "0e1b0e72-78ba-4c61-a4fd-a73788034de1",
          "webhookUsed": "false",
          "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
          "intentName": "get drink"
        },
        "fulfillment": {
          "speech": "",
          "messages": [
            {
              "type": 0,
              "speech": ""
            }
          ]
        },
        "score": 1
      },
      "status": {
        "code": 200,
        "errorType": "success"
      },
      "sessionId": "8b0891c1-50c8-43c6-99c4-8f77261acf86"
    }
```